# How to download Microsoft Academic Graph?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Is it possible to download the entire Microsoft Academic Graph? On [this page](https://kddcup2016.azurewebsites.net/Data) they give a link but there are no download options there.

I know I can use API and I like it, but I am still curious about a download option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://academicgraph.blob.core.windows.net/graph/index.html

it's apparently not possible anymore via single dump, you'll need an Azure subscription and go through the Cognitive Services API

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 6):

I believe you can find the latest data directly in zenodo at: https://zenodo.org/record/2628216

Comment: The is a link-only answer but it's 100% according to the question, so I think it should **not** be removed.

Comment: Did not know zenodo! Thumbs up for you Joao and David. P.s. anyone working there? If so please let me know where I can ping you, I'd like to propose a project embracing open data-

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Academic Graph is available for free from Microsoft, but you'll need an Azure subscription (you can get one for free).

Please see documentation for the service at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/graph/

Answer (score 1):

Please visit [Microsoft Academic Knowledge Graphs (MAKG)](http://ma-graph.org/) for MAKG RDF Dumps